# How to call createContext with React/TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi :) I'm running into an issue when trying to set up context with `createContext`. I need/want to access `state` and `dispatch` in my child components.

I'd also like to know: **is the way I'm trying to pass down `state` and `dispatch` the right way? Or is there another (better) way to do this?**

The error I get: **No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'state'. Either declare one or provide an initializer.**

Here's (part of) my `App.tsx`:

```
interface IState {
  hasStarted: boolean;
  chosenAmount: string;
  chosenCategory: string;
  chosenDifficulty: string;
}

const initialState: IState = {
  hasStarted: false,
  chosenAmount: "",
  chosenCategory: "",
  chosenDifficulty: "",
};

// ... 

interface IStateContext {
  state: IState
  dispatch: React.Dispatch<Action>
}

export const StateContext = createContext<IStateContext>({state, dispatch}); // error here

export const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <StateContext.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>
      {state.hasStarted ? <QuestionsPage /> : <StartPage dispatch={dispatch} />}
    </StateContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Remove the arguments from the createContext function.You don't need them.
`export const StateContext = createContext();`

Comment: @WiseCode You'd think, [but no](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/789ba67e6eae0594e03e740393c275f7b785b0bd/types/react/index.d.ts#L370-L374).

Comment: I found this blog post helpful: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{ a }` is shorthand for: `{ a: a }`

If `a` exists, then this works fine:

```
const a = 123
const obj = { a }
```

But if it does not then you get this error:

```
const obj = { a }
// No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'a'.
//   Either declare one or provide an initializer.(18004)
```

---

Which means that this line:

```
export const StateContext = createContext<IStateContext>({state, dispatch});
```

calls the `createContext` function with an argument that is an object with two values named `state` and `dispatch`.

The problem is that when this function called those values don't exist yet. That's what this error means:

> No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'state'.

Create an object via `{ state }` expects there to be a value named `state` that will be the value of the `state` property of the object.

---

To fix it you need to provide the `createContext()` with a proper default object. That means it must *fully* confirm to the `IStateContext` type.

Something like:

```
const initialState: IState = {
  hasStarted: false,
  chosenAmount: "",
  chosenCategory: "",
  chosenDifficulty: "",
};

export const StateContext = createContext<IStateContext>({
    state: initialState,
    dispatch: (action: Action) => undefined
);
```

---

I, personally, prefer this little hook that will throw an error if a context is used without a provider as a parent. This means you don't need to define a default value at all, and for large and complex contexts, that is really nice.

[useStrictContext()](https://gist.github.com/AlexJWayne/e0f7bb1df814b10aca230891e4640a19)

Comment: Hi @alex! Thank you for your reply. I'm probably implementing your fix the wrong way, but I get this error: Type '{ setHasStarted: () => never; }' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<Action>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'setHasStarted' does not exist in type 'Dispatch<Action>'. See: https://imgur.com/a/4smwBOS. Any idea? :)

Comment: Apparently the type for `Dispatch` is `type Dispatch<A> = (value: A) => void` which is just a function. So `dispatch: (action: Action) => undefined` should work. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

**A complete working sample 8.2022 (react 18):**

```
import React, { createContext, Reducer, useContext, useReducer } from 'react';

interface IState {
    testNum: number
}

interface IPayload {
    something: string;
}

interface IAction {
    type: string;
    payload: Partial<IPayload>;
}

export interface IStateContext {
    context: Partial<IState>
    dispatch: React.Dispatch<IAction>
}

const AppContext = createContext<IStateContext>({
    context: {},
    dispatch: () => undefined
});

const AppReducer = function (state: IState, action: IAction): IState {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'TEST':
            return { ...state, testNum: state.testNum + 1 }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

const AppProvider = ({ children }: { children: any }) => {
    let initState: IState = { testNum: 10 }
    const [context, dispatch] = useReducer<Reducer<IState, IAction>>(AppReducer, initState)

    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={{ context, dispatch }}>
            {children}
        </AppContext.Provider>
    )
}

const C1 = () => {
    const { context, dispatch } = useContext(AppContext)
    return <>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'TEST', payload: {} })}>Clicke To Increment</button>
    </>
}

const C2 = () => {
    const { context } = useContext(AppContext)
    return <div>Value is : {context.testNum}</div>
}

function SinglePageSample() {
    return (
        <AppProvider>
            <C1 />
            <C2 />
        </AppProvider>
    )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SinglePageSample />
  )
}
```